# Dispatch Group for nested loop with order result

Tags: ios, swift

I want to run a for loop in swift in order, DispatchGroup will fire them together, so I want to use DispatchQueue and DispatchSemaphore to achieve my goal. I failed to make my program work, how can I force them to wait and run one by one?

```
 let myGroupMain = DispatchGroup()
    let dispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
    private func requestData(){
        Config.moiTruongTable.queryFeatures(with: queryParams, queryFeatureFields: .loadAll) { [weak self] (result: AGSFeatureQueryResult?, error: Error?) in
        if let features = result?.featureEnumerator().allObjects {
                if !features.isEmpty {
                    self.dispatchQueue.async {
                        for (index, feature) in features.enumerated() {
                            self.myGroupMain.enter()
                            print("index feature: \(index)")
                            let assetsGroup = DispatchGroup()
                            (feature as! AGSArcGISFeature).fetchAttachments { [self] (attachments, error) in
                                print("i: \(index)")
                                if let error = error {
                                } else if let attachments = attachments {
                                    var arrAttachment: [Data] = []
                                    for (index, attachment) in attachments.enumerated() {
                                        assetsGroup.enter()
                                        attachment.fetchData { (data, errr) in
                                            print("index image \(index)")
                                            arrAttachment.append(data!)
                                            assetsGroup.leave()
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                    assetsGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
                                        print("image done")
                                        self.myGroupMain.leave()
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        self.myGroupMain.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
                            print(" FINISHED")
                        })
                    }
```

now out put is

```
index feature: 0
index feature: 1
index feature: 2
index feature: 3
i: 0
image done
i: 2
image done
i: 3
image done
i: 1
```

but i want output

```
index feature: 0
i: 0
image done
index feature: 1
i: 1
image done
index feature: 2
i: 2
image done
```

Comment: If you dont need to launch this app/ship this code until Q4, you might wanna have a look at the new Async/Await Swift Concurrency language features and get rid of this ”pyramid of doom”.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like following call has some issues -

```
(feature as! AGSArcGISFeature).fetchAttachments {
```

Here's what you can try -

```
let assetsGroup = DispatchGroup()

// Add this call here
assetsGroup.enter()

(feature as! AGSArcGISFeature).fetchAttachments { [self] (attachments, error) in
    print("i: \(index)")
    if let error = error {

        // Add this call to handle the error case
        assetsGroup.leave()

    } else if let attachments = attachments {

        var arrAttachment: [Data] = []

        // Add this part 
        var attachmentsFetchDataCounter = attachments.count
        if attachmentsFetchDataCounter == 0 {
            assetsGroup.leave()
        }
        else {
            for (index, attachment) in attachments.enumerated() {
                assetsGroup.enter()
                attachment.fetchData { (data, errr) in
                    print("index image \(index)")
                    arrAttachment.append(data!)
                    assetsGroup.leave()
                    
                    // Add this part
                    attachmentsFetchDataCounter -= 1
                    if attachmentsFetchDataCounter == 0 {
                        assetsGroup.leave()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Note how this is now outside of `fetchAttachments` block
assetsGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
    print("image done")
    self.myGroupMain.leave()
})
```

Comment: i've try with your code, but output still wrong
`index feature: 0
index feature: 1
index feature: 2
index feature: 3
index feature: 4
i: 0
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
i: 4
`

Comment: See the update to the last part - `Note how this is now outside of fetchAttachments block`

Comment: i've move assetsGroup.notify outside of `fetchAttachments` block, it's still print all index feature first, one more thing, some attachments have count = 0, so maybe it's not run in loop

Comment: I have updated the answer to handle `attachmentsFetchDataCounter == 0` case.

Comment: still wrong output, all index feature always print first..

Comment: Well, if you want to freeze the current thread with each async call - you could use `DispatchSemaphore.wait`/`signal` instead. Current code is still `async` - it will perform all of your requests as soon as it can - and let you know when all of them are done. From the code, it looks like you don't need to block subsequent operations until previous ones are finished.

Comment: so where i can put it in my code? i'm newbie with this one :/

Comment: This is how you would implement this with `DispatchGroup`, You should probably ask a new question on how to get this done sequentially (by waiting for previous task).